# Can a 555 be used to control the charging and discharging of a capacitor to provide bursts of current?

Tags: solar-cell, 555, switching

I have a solar cell that charges a capacitor. I want to switch on a motor when a voltage level is reached and then switch off again at a lower voltage or when the capacitor is discharged. I modelled this in a simulator using a 555 by connecting diodes to ground on the threshold and trigger and then 10K resistors to the supply rail. The 555 was powered from the capacitor. I tried this with an actual 555 with an LED on the output. The real system always reach a stable state. Can what I am trying to do be done? How do I change the circuit to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

why would you use a NE555 for something like that? You just want to switch on a transistor above a certain voltage threshold, and then later switch it off as soon as your voltage falls below another level.

In other words: you want a [Schmitt trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger):

[image: Schmitt trigger]

you could actually simply copy the circuit from the above linked wikipedia article:
[image: Schmitt trigger NPN]

V_ would be your ground, V+ would optimally be some kind of stable voltage source (e.g. a linear/low-dropout 3.3V regulator) and Vin would be the voltage across a voltage divider. Vout would then be used to switch a MOSFET:

[image: Schmitt trigger real life]

You can follow the method described in the wikipedia article to select RC1, RC2 and RE, and still have the freedom to select Ri1 and Ri2 to "fine-tune" your input range (e.g. use a trimmer/poti to "prescale" your voltages).

Comment: Can you point me at a real life example of this? How do I change the voltages at which it triggers?

Comment: There; didn't test it, so don't blame me if it doesn't work :) Obviously assumes your cell produces more than 3.3 V.

Comment: I want to run everything off the solar cell. Its low power. I'm not sure there is enough to start running regulators. I was hoping for a solution where the resistors were swapped out for diodes. Resistors are great for dividing down a reference voltage. I was hoping to not need this.

Comment: well, every circuit you'll build will inevitably depend on some supply voltage. Your NE555 doesn't work without one, either!

Comment: The charging capacitor is the supply, which is varying, therefore dividers do not work, as the ratio stays the same, thats why i was considering diodes.

Comment: yep, but with a diode you'd still need to control something else, and that will have transistors, and these will only work sufficiently well given a supply voltage. In any case, a NE555 needs at least 4.5V, which is significantly more than what the circuitry above could work with.

Comment: Also notice that as far as I can tell, this circuit should stay off as long as there's no sufficient supply voltage, so it still works in the desired way.